# How to get DatePart out of datetime result column in SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a column `StartDateTime` which has the Value `2/10/2008 6:30:12` 
  I need only the Date part  i.e `2/10/2008` to be retrieved.
  I tried using `strftime()` and `date()` functions in `sqlite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not one of the [supported date/time formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

Store your date/times in the format `2008-10-02 06:30:12` instead.